# Is there a term for step-sibling of a step-sibling?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

So here's the situation:

Boy 2 and Boy 3, unrelated, both have Boy 1 as their stepbrother and meet each other occasionally.

What would we call their relationship? Is there a term for it, or should I invent one (Lol)?

[I got curious from watching a similar situation in a K-drama.]

Comment: The best I can give you is they are now brothers in a *blended family*.

Comment: English is very limited in its family terminology. I'm pretty sure there's no word for this. It probably doesn't come up enough to need a term.

Comment: If Boys 2 and 3 are unrelated, then why would there be a name for the relationship they do not have?

Comment: I doubt any language has a standard word for this.  But I occasionally call the half-sister of my own step-siblings my *step-stepsister*.

Comment: A step-brother of a step-brother is a **stair-brother**.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities I can think of.

The first is a broader usage of "cousin".

The second is kin, or kindred, kinfolk, kinsmen. These are closer in meaning but are rare.

Depending on the circumstances, you could use other archaic words like clans, etc.

Ironically your post is tagged as kinship terms.

Comment: Although some people would say the children aren't really related, so it's inappropriate to use kinship terms. But I don't think there are any better options than these, so I hope it's good enough.